# Does "Saint Seiya Omega" series have a prequel?

Tags: saint-seiya, saint-seiya-omega

When Saint Seiya Omega starts, there is an evil character named Mars, which seems to be defeated by saints before. But I have never seen him in the previous series. Some of the plot is built on past events about which we are assumed to have a priori knowledge. It is strongly like this series have a prequel.

I have watched these TV series:

- Saint Seiya
- Saint Seiya - Hades Chapter OVA - Sanctuary
- Saint Seiya - Hades Chapter OVA - Inferno
- Saint Seiya - Hades Chapter OVA - Elision
- Saint Seiya - The Lost Canvas

But still I can't tie up any of them with the currently ongoing Saint Seiya Omega series.

Does "Saint Seiya Omega" have a prequel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing which comes between Elision and Omega is the movie
[Saint Seiya: The Heaven Chapter - Overture](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1259/Saint_Seiya%3a_The_Heaven_Chapter_-_Overture). The Lost Canvas is a prequel.

However, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Seiya_Omega), it is an anime-original story separate from the original continuity, and you aren't assumed to have watched all the previous series. As far as I know, Mars only appears in Omega, so there are definitely some unexplained points which might get answered in flashbacks or might remain forever unexplained.

Answer (score 0):

Saint Seiya Omega Does not have a prequel.

Mars was created exclusively for saint seiya Omega, and all the background we get from his previous battle against the saints is told during Saint Seiya Omega.